# C# class structure for inconsistent JSON strings

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to deserialize this piece of JSON into C# (The outer string increases to the hundreds):

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
    "price": 12.64,
    "sold": 381
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)",
    "price": 35.55,
    "sold": 190
  }
}
```

The problem here is that this JSON is structured a bit different than what I'm used to, as the Root here seems like a List.

I've tried to create classes I thought would be correct (I do not know what the name of the list should be):

```
public class BpRoot
{ 
    public List<BpInfo> items { get; set; }
}
public class BpInfo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string sold { get; set; }
}
```

But after deserializing the JSON with the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` method, and trying to print them out in the console, it simply returns null.

So how would I structure the classes if the root object is a list?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks more like it should be a dictionary than a list to me. And it looks consistent. What's inconsistent about it?

Comment: Read [ask], share your research, see duplicate. `public Dictionary<string, BpInfo> items { get; set; }`.

Comment: I did try that aswell, however it still returns null

Comment: Your JSON isn't a collection/array/list. "1" and "2" are both keys and the right of the ":" is an object. As @mason said you likely need a Dictionary

Comment: The root isn't a list it's an object/key value pair. I agree with mason, I think you should be using a Dictionary<string, BpInfo>